# D3 zoom in on brush extent

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a web tool that should create a scatterplot with given data. Since I am new to anything visualizing (and not an expert on JavaScript either), I decided going with D3.

Following tutorials, observing examples and trying stuff I got a scatterplot going with brush selection (which does nothing yet).
Now since thegoal is plotting genes, a lot of them will be extremely close to each other in terms of x and y coordinates. So I would like to implement something [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/7612013), but in both the x and y direction. Basically zoom in on the brushed section.

So far I am unable to create this behaviour, at this point my axes do change, but no longer show values and none of the zooming happens. You can see it live on [my toy subdomain](http://medvis.laureif80.eighty.axc.nl/). I am not sure where it goes wrong, so any help is appreciated.

The javascript used on the toy domain:

```
// General variables

var svg, width, height;
var padding = 30;

var dataset = [
              [ 5,     20 ],
              [ 480,   90 ],
              [ 250,   50 ],
              [ 100,   33 ],
              [ 330,   95 ],
              [ 410,   12 ],
              [ 475,   44 ],
              [ 25,    67 ],
              [ 85,    21 ],
              [ 220,   88 ]
          ];

function drawGraph(){
    scatterplot_area_size = $("#scatterplot").width();
    width = scatterplot_area_size;
    height = scatterplot_area_size * 0.75;

    console.log(width);

    // Retrieve the interval of the x and y data
    var maxX = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[0];  //References first value in each sub-array
    });

    var minX = d3.min(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[0];  //References first value in each sub-array
    });

    var maxY = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1];  //References second value in each sub-array
    });

    var minY = d3.min(dataset, function(d) {
        return d[1];  //References second value in each sub-array
    });

    // Create a (square) scatterplot area in the div with id scatterplot
    // which spans the entire div in width
    svg = d3.select("#scatterplot")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

    // plot all points
    var points = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "point")
        .selectAll("point")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");


    console.log(minX + " " + minY);

    // Create x and y scales
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([minX, maxX])
                     .range([padding, (width-padding)]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([minY, maxY])
                     .range([(height-padding), padding]); // Reverse the scale to let high values show at the top and low values at the bottom

    // Set the x and y positions as well as the radius (hard coded 5)
    points.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
    })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("r", 5);

    // Create the x and y axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .ticks(10)
                  .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .ticks(10)
                  .orient("left");

    // Add the axes to the scatterplot
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height-padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Allow for brushing (selection of points)
    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("brushend", brushend);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .selectAll('rect')
        .attr('height', height);

    function brushmove() {
      var extent = brush.extent();
      points.classed("selected", function(d) {
        return extent[0][0] <= d[0] && d[0] <= extent[1][0]
                && extent[0][1] <= d[1] && d[1] <= extent[1][1];
      });
    }

    function brushend() {
        x.domain(brush.extent());
        y.domain(brush.extent());

        transition_data();
        reset_axis();

        points.classed("selected", false);
        d3.select(".brush").call(brush.clear());
    }

    function transition_data() {
        console.log("transistion data called");
        d3.selectAll("point")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { console.log(d[0]); return x(d[0]); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
    }

    function reset_axis() {
        svg.transition().duration(500)
        .select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis);

        svg.transition().duration(500)
        .select(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis);
    }
}

// Wait until the document is loaded, then draw the graph.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    drawGraph();
});

// If the window is resized, redraw graph to make it fit again.
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if(typeof svg != 'undefined'){
        $("#scatterplot").empty();
    } 
    drawGraph();
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, my console shows no errors or warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. In your function `brushend()` you are setting the domains of your scales using the return value of `brush.extent()` in both cases. Notice, however, that the extent returned by your brush is a two-dimensional array like `[[xMin,yMin],[xMax,yMax]]`. You have to set your domains using

   ```
   var extent = brush.extent();
   x.domain([extent[0][0],extent[1][0]]);  // x.domain([xMin,xMax])
   y.domain([extent[0][1],extent[1][1]]);  // y.domain([yMin,yMax])
   ```

   These adjustments will have your axes scale correctly while the points are still fixed.
2. You are inserting and manipulating your data points with `d3.selectAll("point")` which refers to them as being of type `svg:point`. However, there is no such type of svg element. Though your call to `d3.selectAll("point")` is still valid it will always yield an empty selection because there is no element to be selected. For this reason your first call to the function when setting up the svg does work, since it will put all the data bound to the enter selection giving the desired result. For the sake of correctness you should correct this to

   ```
   // plot all points
   var points = svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "point")
       // .selectAll("point")
       .selectAll("circle")    // <-- This will work
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("circle");
   ```

   When trying to update your points after having set the scales' domains the faulty code will not work because in this case the empty selection is meaningless and will have no effect on any element. Since in the above quoted statement you have already stored a reference to your selection in `var points` there is no need to select them again. You could just rewrite your update as follows:

   ```
   function transition_data() {
       // d3.selectAll("point")   // Instead of this...
       points                     // <-- ...use the reference to your selection
           .transition()
           .duration(500)
           .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
   }
   ```

I put together a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcom2yq4/) to demonstrate the solution.